# How to get Firestore collectionGroup datas as an Observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, observable

From the https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries documentation snippet, Im unable to get the results as an Observable

```
import { collectionGroup, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";  

const museums = query(collectionGroup(db, 'landmarks'), where('type', '==', 'museum'));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(museums);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
});
```

So I wrote it like this:

```
const museums = query(
  collectionGroup(db, 'landmarks'),
  where('type', '==', 'museum')
);
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(museums);
const datas = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
  return doc.data() as Data;
});
console.log(datas);
return of(datas);
```

But I'm not getting results when subscribing to it or in the DOM using async pipe, but when I console.log(), there is an array of data.

component.html

```
{{ museums_data$ | async }}
```

component.ts

```
this.museums_data$.subscribe((datas) => console.log(datas));
```

Comment: How did you find 'not getting results'?

Comment: Sorry, I should add more context. It does not appear in the DOM or when I use Subscribe.

Comment: How do you assign the observable to `museum_data$`? Please share the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it here: https://code.build/p/LWmSi3HfQzu5TMKPzb5p6i/angular-12-with-firebase-9, which is written for the collection. Assuming it should also work for collection groups, I tried it, and it performed as expected.

This is a code snippet found in the link:

```
collectionData<Post>(
      query<Post>(
        collection(this.afs, 'posts') as CollectionReference<Post>,
        where('published', '==', true)
      ), { idField: 'id' }
    );
```

to:

```
collectionData<Landmark>(
      query<Landmark>(
        collectionGroup(db, 'landmarks') as CollectionReference<Landmark>,
        where('type', '==', 'museum')
      ), { idField: 'id' }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

At First glance code looks good but you are returning it incorrectly. Instead of mapping over you can return it directly using `as Observable<Data[]>`. Although I have not considered the error handling this can easily be achieved using the `catchError` rxjs operator.

You can use the following technique to get the data as you want using an `async` pipe.

**data.service.ts** :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { collection, collectionData, Firestore, query, where
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Data } from './data';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
constructor(private db: Firestore) {}
  getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
    const ref = collection(this.db, "landmarks");
    const q = query(ref, where("type", "==", "museum"));
    const data = collectionData(q, {
      idField: 'id',
    });
    return data as Observable<Data[]>;
  }
```

And use it like this in the corresponding component:

**app.component.ts** :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Data } from './data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  museums_data$!: Observable<Data[]>;
  constructor(private service: DataService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.museums_data$ = this.service.getData();
  }
}
```

And

**app.component.html** :

```
<div *ngFor="let museum of museums_data$ | async">
  {{ museum.id }}
  //...
</div>
```

For more information there is [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/angular-13-firebase-crud-tutorial-with-angularfire-7-2d6980dcc091) that explains nicely.